# Can you earn badges while suspended

Tags: support, bug, badges

I was recently suspended from this website for a seven day period. During this time I continued to log onto the site each day and earned the Enthusiast Badge for logging on for 30 consecutive days.

Is this a bug or can you earn badges whilst suspended?

Comment: You can earn badges (and reputation) while suspended. I would call earning the Enthusiast badge in a suspension period an edge case but on the other hand, if you're that dedicated that you, despite a suspension, still visit the site daily is maybe worth a badge anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not a bug. If I posted an excellent answer before a suspension, and it reaches +25 score during that suspension, then I might as well unlock that Good Answer badge then, because if it's still +25 when the suspension ends I would get it at that point.

Suspension really just blocks all actions that you take; once it ends, it will appear to anyone but a ♦moderator that you were merely lurking during that period.

As rene said, you *deserve* that badge if you're dedicated enough to log on while suspended.

Comment: Adding to that, you can still earn **Enthusiast** and **Fanatic** :)